# Тип всего выражения

Tags: c++

Недавно написал такую функцию:

```
template<class T>
bool isAvailableSpace(int size, int capacity){
    return capacity - size - sizeof(T) >= 0;
}
```

`capacity` - вместимость какого-то буфера
`size` - количество занятых байт.
Функция проверяет достаточно ли в буфере места для объекта типа `T`. Проблема оказалось в том, что результат выражения `capacity - size - sizeof(T)` получался unsigned из за `sizeof`. Таким образом функция всегда возвращала `true`.

Собственно вопрос: почему так? В выражении участвовали знаковые и беззнаковые переменные, почему компилятор отдал предпочтение беззнаковым?

Comment: Потому что беззнаковый считается более широким типом.

Comment: size и capacity обычно не бывают меньше нуля, поэтому, я бы их тип поменял на size_t и условие переписал как `return capacity >= size + sizeof(T);`

Comment: @KoVadim, именно так я и поступил. Однако все же было интересно чем руководствуется компилятор.

Comment: стандартом и мыслями разработчиков.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Так как `size_t` является беззнаковым типом, а `int` знаковым, и ранг `size_t` не меньше ранга `int`, то из текущего черновика стандарта [п.8/11](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr#11) следует, что в данном случае будет выполнено целочисленное продвижение (integral promotion) и [результатом выражения стенет беззнаковый тип](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr#11.5.3):

> Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank greater than or equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, the operand with signed integer type shall be converted to the type of the operand with unsigned integer type.

Небольшой [пример для демонстрации](https://wandbox.org/permlink/0WO7PO1N6Ykko8gN):

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int i = 100;
    size_t st = 42;
    unsigned short us = 42;
    std::cout << st - i << "\n"; // size_t
    std::cout << us - i << "\n"; // int 
}
```

> ```
> 18446744073709551558    
> -58
> ```

В первом случае выражение имеет тип `size_t`, беззнаковый, т.е. ситуация аналогичная описанной в вопросе. Во втором случае - ранг `unsigned short` меньше, чем ранг `int` и результат - `int`, т.е. знаковый тип.